# Arduino callback stops working when there is a new connection to MQTT broker

Tags: websocket, callback, arduino, mqtt

First time posting on here, I am hoping somebody will be able to give me some help with an annoying problem I a having.

I am trying to control an Arduino through MQTT with websockets this all works fine until a new connection to the broker is made, the Arduino then does not respond to the callbacks.

```
    #include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>

// Update these with values suitable for your network.
byte mac[]    = {  0xDE, 0xED, 0xBA, 0xFE, 0xFE, 0xED };
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 0, 123);
const char* server = "192.168.0.30";
char message_buff[100];

// defines and variable for sensor/control mode
#define MODE_OFF    0  // not sensing light, LED off
#define MODE_ON     1  // not sensing light, LED on
#define MODE_SENSE  2  // sensing light, LED controlled by software
int senseMode = 0;
unsigned long time;

EthernetClient ethClient;
PubSubClient mqttClient(ethClient);
void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  int i = 0;
  for (int i=0;i<length;i++) {
   message_buff[i] = payload[i];
  }


   String msgString = String(message_buff);
   Serial.println("Payload: " + msgString);
  if (msgString.equals("onn")){
      senseMode = MODE_ON;

    }else if(msgString.equals("off")){
     senseMode = MODE_OFF;

    }


}
void reconnect() {
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  while (!mqttClient.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    // Attempt to connect
    if (mqttClient.connect("arduinoClient")) {
      Serial.println("connected");
      // Once connected, publish an announcement...
      mqttClient.publish("test","AR1 Connected");
      // ... and resubscribe
      mqttClient.subscribe("test");
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");

      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
  mqttClient.setServer(server, 1883);
  mqttClient.setCallback(callback);

  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  // Allow the hardware to sort itself out
  delay(1500);

}

void loop()
{
  if (!mqttClient.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }
    switch (senseMode) {
    case MODE_OFF:
      // light should be off
      digitalWrite(7, LOW);
      break;
    case MODE_ON:
      // light should be on
      digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
      break;
    }
  mqttClient.loop();
}
```

Outputs:

```
Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc= try again in 5 seconds
Attempting MQTT connection...connected
Payload: onn
Payload: off
Payload: JTPA.CONNECTED
Payload: onnA.CONNECTED
Payload: offA.CONNECTED
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Edit the question to include the serial output so we can see what is actually happening. Also unless something has changed, the PubSubClient does not support MQTT over websockets. and a connection to  port 1883 is very likely to be native MQTT not MQTT over websockets.

Comment: Sorry didn't explain everything properly, the Arduino is connected through the standard MQTT Socket 1883, I also then have a web server running which connects through the websockets. Whent he web server connects first then the Arduino everything works ok, but when a new client connects to the MQTT server the Arduino does not respond.

Comment: You still haven't added any of the serial output to the question so we can see what is happening. Also clarify how many Arduinos you have running this code. The code has a hard coded client id which will not work with more than one instance

Comment: Thank you for the advice. This has highlighted the issue but i am still unsure on how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

As thrashed out in the comments the problem here is that you are using the same MQTT client ID for all instances. This will not work as every client needs a unique id and the broker will disconnect duplicates.

You need a way to generate a unique id, this [question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/279/how-can-i-get-a-unique-id-for-all-my-arduino-boards) on the Arduino site has some hints on how to do this.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.I Only the 1 Arduino, and I have put the serial monitor out put on and this has highlighted the issue, it switches fine in the first two "onn" and "off" but when the new client connects, the website it publish's "JTPA.CONNECTED" then when the "onn" "off" commands are being sent again half of the string is left in the m"message but i am still unsure on how to fix this.